# Evaluation *and transcendence* of $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(mp)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

How can we evaluate the sum $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(mp)!}$, where $p$ is a fixed prime?

It is a subseries of the exponential series, but the its evaluation is out of my knowledge. Is the sum transcendental, like $e$? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Do we have $(mp)!$ or $m\cdot p!$ in the denominator ?

Comment: For $\ p=2\ $ , the sum is $\ \cosh(1)-1\ $ , which is transcendental. Not sure about other primes $\ p\ $.

Comment: @Peter It is $(mp)!$

Comment: If it’s $(mp)!$ in the denominator, then the sum is $-1+\frac{1}{p}\sum_{\omega^p=1}{e^{\omega}}$. By using the second formulation on Wikipedia of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem (considering the $e^{\omega}$ and $1=e^0$), we find that the sum is transcendental.

Comment: @Mindlack Could you elaborate on how that is the sum?

Comment: Just expand the exponentials and recall that $\sum_{\omega^p=1}{\omega^k}$ is $p$ if $p|k$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Mindlack Please work that out more detailed. In particular, how can we conclude that the sum is transcendental ?

Comment: @Mindlack So the sum includes $1$ as part of the roots of unity, but $1+\omega+\ldots \omega^{p-1}=0$ so they're not linearly independent over $\Bbb{Q}$? Wikipedia says something about 'distinct' roots but doesn't define what that means. Unless it means roots of an irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}$ or something?

Comment: @snulty: I’m using the *second formulation* on Wikipedia of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem. The one saying that exponentials of distinct algebraic numbers are linearly independent over the algebraic numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha seems to be able to do some of these sums, it doesn't look like there's a $-1$.

Following @Mindlack's comment.

Let $\omega$ be a primitive $p$'th root of unity.

$$\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}e^{\omega^j}=\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\omega^{jn}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{p-1} \frac{\omega^{jn}}{n!}=\sum_{p\not\mid n }^\infty\frac{(\omega^n)^p-1}{\omega^n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{p\mid n }^\infty\cdot\frac{p}{n!}=p\sum_{m=0 }^\infty\frac{1}{(mp)!}$$

where we can use absolute convergence to rearrange the sums.

So that

$$\frac{1}{p}\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}e^{\omega^j}=\sum_{m=0 }^\infty\frac{1}{(mp)!}$$

Edit:

Then
$$\sum_{m=1 }^\infty\frac{1}{(mp)!}=-1+\frac{1}{p}\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}e^{\omega^j}$$

I don't know much of the details in showing it's transcendental. However again as @Mindlack suggests a form of the Lindemann–Weierstrass Theorem (Baker's reformulation) cited for convenience from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)  — If $a_1, ..., a_n$ are algebraic numbers, and $\alpha_1, ...,\alpha_n$ are distinct algebraic numbers, then

$$a_{1}e^{\alpha _{1}}+a_{2}e^{\alpha _{2}}+\cdots +a_{n}e^{\alpha _{n}}=0$$

has only the trivial solution $a_i=0, \forall i\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$.

Comment: (Small nitpick – OP is excluding zero from the original sum, hence the $-1$).

Comment: @Mindlack ah thanks I'm blind!

Comment: (+1) I don't believe there is a need for $p$ to be prime (as you allude). This holds for any positive integer.

Answer (score 2):

As one could expect, the result is an hypergeometric function. Tos how the pattern for
$$S_n=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(m\,p_n)!}$$
$$S_3=\,
   _0F_4\left(;\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5};\frac{1}{5 ^5}\right
   )-1$$
$$S_4=\,
   _0F_6\left(;\frac{1}{7},\frac{2}{7},\frac{3}{7},\frac{4}{7},\frac{5}{7},\frac{6}
   {7};\frac{1}{7^7}\right)-1$$
$$S_5=\,
   _0F_{10}\left(;\frac{1}{11},\frac{2}{11},\frac{3}{11},\frac{4}{11},\frac{5}{11},
   \frac{6}{11},\frac{7}{11},\frac{8}{11},\frac{9}{11},\frac{10}{11};\frac{1}{11^{11}}\right)-1$$
$$\color{red}{S_n=\,
   _0F_{p_n-1}\left(;\frac{1}{p_n},\frac{2}{p_n},\cdots,
   \frac{p_n-1}{p_n};\frac{1}{p_n^{p_n}}\right)-1}$$
The only ones which have a simple expression are
$$S_1=\cosh (1)-1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad S_2=\frac{e}{3}+\frac{2 \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{3 \sqrt{e}}-1$$

Withe regards to their numerical values , they vary so fast and become so small that I prefered to report their natural logarithms.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \log(S_n) \\
 1 & -0.61049747133410909146051941159 \\
 2 & -1.78344425637725042342833013579 \\
 3 & -4.78745867445397438463060951630 \\
 4 & -8.52516130325285806010595721194 \\
 5 & -17.5023078458738503261433874907 \\
 6 & -22.5521638531234228701303523219 \\
 7 & -33.5050734501368888840079011626 \\
 8 & -39.3398841871994940362246523943 \\
 9 & -51.6066755677643735704464024823 \\
 10 & -71.2570389671680090100744070426 \\
 11 & -78.0922235533153106314168080587 \\
 12 & -99.3306124547874269293260866847 \\
 13 & -114.034211781461703232920297987 \\
 14 & -121.533081515438633962310970602 \\
 15 & -136.802722637326368469643563853 \\
 16 & -160.331128216630907028214394529 \\
 17 & -184.533828861449490502457941577 \\
 18 & -192.739047287844902436039799493 \\
 19 & -217.736934113954227250984171593 \\
 20 & -234.701723442818267742722967253
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: any hints for transcendentalness?

Comment: @vidyarthi. Brrrrrrrrrrrrrrr !

Comment: seeing the other answer, I think they are transcendental. So are hypergeometric numbers transcendental?

Answer (score 1):

For any positive integer $m$, prime or not, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}e^{e^{2\pi ik/m}}-1
&=\frac1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{e^{2\pi ijk/m}}{j!}-1\tag1\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac1{j!}\color{#C00}{\frac1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}e^{2\pi ijk/m}}-1\tag2\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{\color{#C00}{[m\mid j]}}{j!}-1\tag3\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{(mj)!}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: use the Taylor series for $e^x$
$(2)$: change the order of summation
$(3)$: $\frac1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}e^{2\pi ijk/m}=[m\mid j]$
$(4)$: keep only the terms where $m\mid j$

Since each $e^{2\pi ik/m}$ is algebraic, [Lindemann-Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) says the left side of $(1)$ is transcendental.

The imaginary part of the left side of $(1)$ is
$$
\frac1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}e^{\cos(2\pi k/m)}\sin(\sin(2\pi k/m))=0\tag5
$$
because the $k=0$ term is $0$ and the $k$ and $m-k$ terms cancel. This is good, since we expect the sum to be real.

Thus, $(4)$ and $(5)$ say that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{(mj)!}
=\frac1m\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}e^{\cos(2\pi k/m)}\cos(\sin(2\pi k/m))-1\tag6
$$
Note that for $m\ge3$, at least graphically, the log of the sum in $(6)$ and $-\log(m!)$ are indistinguishable:

[image]